# Error C2664 'HRESULT IUnknown::QueryInterface(const IID &,void **)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const winrt::guid' to 'const IID &'

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, c++-cx, c++-winrt

This error happens to me when I use the helper function from [microsoft docs to migrate to winrt from cx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/interop-winrt-cx). I see a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56720866/using-winrtcom-ptrid3d11device1-with-d3d11createdevice), but the solution mentioned doesn't seem to work for me. The solution mentioned here add #include <Unknwn.h> before any other winrt headers in the file which has this error.

```
template <typename T>
T from_cx(Platform::Object ^ from) {
T to{nullptr};

winrt::check_hresult(reinterpret_cast<::IUnknown*>(from)->QueryInterface(
    winrt::guid_of<T>(), reinterpret_cast<void**>(winrt::put_abi(to))));

return to;
}
```

This is the entire file:

```
#pragma once

#include <Unknwn.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.h>

namespace x {
namespace y {

template <typename T>
T from_cx(Platform::Object ^ from) {
    T to{nullptr};

    winrt::check_hresult(reinterpret_cast<::IUnknown*>(from)->QueryInterface(
        winrt::guid_of<T>(), reinterpret_cast<void**>(winrt::put_abi(to))));

    return to;
}

template <typename T>
    T ^
    to_cx(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IUnknown const& from) {
        return safe_cast<T ^>(reinterpret_cast<Platform::Object ^>(winrt::get_abi(from)));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If you `#include <Unknwn.h>`, make sure you **really** include it prior to any winrt headers. When using precompiled headers, that's where you have to include *Unknwn.h* as well.

Comment: Hi I made an edit above adding the entire contents of the file. I do have the include before any other header.

Comment: You have posted a header file. Header files aren't compilation units. It's vital that your *compilation units* have the *Unknwn.h* included before any other winrt header files. Compilation units commonly have a file extension of .cpp, .cc, or .cxx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`winrt::guid_of()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/guid-of) returns a `winrt::guid`.  Per [What's new in C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/news):

> - **Breaking change**. GUID is now projected as `winrt::guid`. For APIs that you implement, you must use `winrt::guid` for GUID parameters. Otherwise, `winrt::guid` converts to GUID, **as long as you include unknwn.h before you include any C++/WinRT headers**. See [Interoperating with the ABI's GUID struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/interop-winrt-abi#interoperating-with-the-abis-guid-struct).

Per [Interoperating with the ABI's GUID struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/interop-winrt-abi#interoperating-with-the-abis-guid-struct):

> `GUID` is projected as `winrt::guid`. For APIs that you implement, you must use `winrt::guid` for `GUID` parameters. Otherwise, there are automatic conversions between `winrt::guid` and `GUID` **as long as you include `unknwn.h` (implicitly included by <windows.h> and many other header files) before you include any C++/WinRT headers**.
>
> If you don't do that, then you can hard-`reinterpret_cast` between them.

So, either make sure `unknwn.h` is included before WinRT headers, or else you can `reinterpret_cast` explicitly, eg:

```cpp
template <typename T>
T from_cx(Platform::Object ^ from) {
    T to{nullptr};
    winrt::guid iid = winrt::guid_of<T>();

    winrt::check_hresult(
        reinterpret_cast<::IUnknown*>(from)->QueryInterface(
            reinterpret_cast<GUID&>(iid),
            reinterpret_cast<void**>(winrt::put_abi(to)))
    );

    return to;
}
```

Comment: @ssn I updated my example. If it still errors, then show the actual error

Answer (score 0):

IInspectable's comment also worked for me:

> If you #include <Unknwn.h>, make sure you really include it prior to
> any winrt headers. When using precompiled headers, that's where you
> have to include Unknwn.h as well.
>
> .....It's vital that your compilation units have the Unknwn.h included
> before any other winrt header files. Compilation units commonly have a
> file extension of .cpp, .cc, or .cxx.

I thought the header had to be included in the file defining those helper functions.